# How to fill a column from a data frame based on another data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames and I am trying to replace NAs in a column of the second data frame using the values in a column of the first data frame. I would like to do this using the `dplyr` package and I am not familiar with this package:

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
## Create the two data frames
      dt1 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6)), day = c(seq(0, 5, by= 1), seq(0, 5, by= 1), seq(0, 5, by= 1)), density = sample(1:100, 6*3))
      dt2 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6)), day = c(seq(0, 5, by= 1), seq(0, 5, by= 1), seq(0, 5, by= 1)), density = NA)

## Fill the second data frame
     dt2[dt2$day == 0, c("density")] <- c(1, 2, 8)
     dt2[dt2$day %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c("density")] <- dt1[dt1$day %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), c("density")] 
## the values in the column "ID" of dt1 must be equivalent to the values in the column "ID" of dt2
```

How can I reproduce the two last commands using the `dplyr` package ?

Here is my test:

```
  dt2_fill <- dt2 %>% 
    mutate(density = if(day == 0){c(1, 2, 8)},
           density = if(day %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)){dt1[dt1$day %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), c("density")]})
```

But this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an ideal solution but gives expected output

A complete `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
dt2 %>%
  filter(day == 0) %>%
  mutate(density = c(1, 2, 8)) %>%
  bind_rows(dt2 %>%
              filter(day %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %>%
              mutate(density = dt1 %>%
                              filter(day %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) %>% 
                               pull(density)
             ))

#   ID day density
#1   1   0       1
#2   2   0       2
#3   3   0       8
#4   1   1      84
#5   1   2      72
#6   1   3       4
#7   1   4      31
#....
```

We first `filter` the rows for `day == 0` and assign the values `c(1, 2, 8)` to them. For remaining rows we get the corresponding `density` column from `dt1`.

---

We can reduce a bit of complexity by

```
dt2 %>%
   filter(day == 0) %>%
   mutate(density = c(1, 2, 8)) %>%
   bind_rows(dt2 %>%
              filter(day %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %>%
              mutate(density = dt1$density[dt1$day %in% c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)])
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're trying to do here, at least in practice, is merge two data frames. Your `ID` and `day` variables work as unique identifiers, except that the `day` variable in dt1 is off by one in dt2. So what about a solution like this:

```
dt2 <- dt1 %>% 
  mutate(day = day + 1) %>% # Adjust "day" variable to line up with the "day" variable in dt2
  right_join(dt2 %>% select(-density), by = c("ID", "day"))
```

That will leave NAs in the density variable for cases where `day == 0`. You could solve that using the filter/bind-rows solution that Ronak suggests above, or you could assign those cases using `ifelse` statements like so:

```
dt2 <- dt2 %>% 
  mutate(density = ifelse(day > 0, density,
                          ifelse(ID == 1, 1,
                                 ifelse(ID == 2, 2, 8))))
```

(This is a bit kludge-y, and I suspect there might be a better solution in your real-world case if you want to provide more details.)

Another option is just to create your dt2 data frame directly from dt1:

```
dt2 <- dt1 %>% 
  mutate(day = day + 1) %>% 
  filter(day < 6) %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(ID = c(1,2,3), day = 0, density = c(1,2,8))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, day)
```